# JEMDOC link does not work with special symbols

Tags: hyperlink, jemdoc

I wish to use JEMDOC's [ ] to link to a page with special symbols in its address like this:

[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%27s_method Fisher's Method]

However JEMDOC sees % as a special symbol, and the link fails.

It also fails when I escape the %, as in \%.

I am wondering if there is a way around this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured it out!

Just replace %27 in the above example with its corresponding character '.